# windows cmd uses local machine's python instead of project's python

Tags: python, batch-file, cmd

I am trying to set up a batch file which checks if the python project has the required modules. I am creating the batch file using the following code:

```
def _write_batch():
    path = ROOT_DIR+"\\setup.bat"
    python_path = sys.executable
    script_path = os.path.abspath(__file__)
    string = f"@echo off\cd core\n{python_path} {script_path}"
    write(path, string)
```

`python_path` points towards the project's python. However when I run the batch file, it checks whether the modules are installed in my local machine's python directory. Is there any way of disabling the local machine's python when running a script?

Comment: Did you mean `@echo off\ncd core...`?

Comment: Yes, this is what I meant

Comment: Is there still a problem if you fix that? Because with the `\c` typo, it's not going to execute `cd core`, obviously.

Comment: yes. The problem is that I want the script to check the project python.exe instead of my local machine's python.exe, so that the project can work on a different machine without any importing issues